# WMS overlay is dislocated in google maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, wms

I can show the wms raster into google maps, but its dislocated. The coordinate system of the image is right, everything seems to be ok, but the raster doesn't fit well .Here is my code:

```
            SLPLayer =
   new google.maps.ImageMapType (
   {
    getTileUrl:
      function (coord, zoom) { 
        var proj = map.getProjection(); 
        var zfactor = Math.pow(2, zoom); 
         // get Long Lat coordinates
        var top = proj.fromPointToLatLng(
               new google.maps.Point(coord.x * 256 / zfactor, coord.y * 256 / zfactor) ); 
        var bot = proj.fromPointToLatLng(
              new google.maps.Point((coord.x + 1) * 256 / zfactor, (coord.y + 1) * 256 / zfactor)); 
        //corrections for the slight shift of the SLP (mapserver)
         var deltaX = 0.0013; 
         var deltaY = 0.00058; 

        //create the Bounding box string
         var bbox = (top.lng() + deltaX) + "," +(bot.lat() + deltaY) +","
                             +(bot.lng() + deltaX) +"," +(top.lat() + deltaY);

         //base WMS URL
         var url ="http://209.41.76.52:8080/geoserver/Caragua/wms?";
         url +="&REQUEST=GetMap"; //WMS operation
         url +="&SERVICE=WMS"; //WMS service
         url +="&VERSION=1.1.0"; //WMS version 
         url +="&LAYERS=" + "Caragua:caraguaauto11gcpsp2merged_transparent_mosaic_group1"; //WMS layers
         url +="&FORMAT=image/png"; //WMS format
         url +="&BGCOLOR=0xFFFFFF" ;
         url +="&TRANSPARENT=TRUE" ;
         url +="&SRS=EPSG:4326"; //set WGS84 3349 ou 4326
         url +="&BBOX="+ bbox; // set bounding box
         url +="&WIDTH=256"; //tile size in google
         url +="&HEIGHT=256" ; 
         console.log(url);
         return url; // return URL for the tile    

       }, //getTileURL
   tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
   isPng: true
   }); 
   //add WMS layer 
   map.overlayMapTypes.push(SLPLayer);
```

Comment: KARAIO HEIN, NINGUÉM MANJA DE NADA NESSA MERDA DESSE SITE.. SÓ HTML E CSS. I'M DONE

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace the first 20 lines of code with the following lines:

```html
            SLPLayer =
   new google.maps.ImageMapType (
   {
    getTileUrl:
      function (coord, zoom) { 
        var proj = map.getProjection();
        var zfactor = Math.pow(2, zoom);                      
        var ul = new google.maps.Point(coord.x * 256.0 / zfactor , (coord.y + 1) * 256.0 / zfactor );
        var lr = new google.maps.Point((coord.x + 1) * 256.0 / zfactor , (coord.y) * 256.0 / zfactor );
        var ulw = proj.fromPointToLatLng(ul);
        var lrw = proj.fromPointToLatLng(lr);                                 
        var bbox = ulw.lng() + "," + ulw.lat() + "," + lrw.lng() + "," + lrw.lat();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Good answers require an explanation of why they work.  Code dumps are less satisfactory.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer